# Print channel id/name into console with discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I need my bot to print in which channel it sents a message. This is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
 await ctx.reply('hello', mention_author=True) 
 channel = #what goes here????
 print('i said hello in', (channel))
```

I've tried all of these:

```
user = bot.get_user(user_id)
message.author.username
username = client.get_user(user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The things you tried are referencing user id. I have not used discord.py in a while, but you will have to reference the channel id and not the user id. Maybe try:

```
ctx.message.channel.id
```

I can't remember if this returns an object or a string so you may have to format further to get the string.